# Posts update without reloading page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I've to do posting application with php,MySql,javascript or jQuery. I know how to send data to database with ajax (without reloading page) , but I am interested in if someone posts something how to be known for others client (without reloding page too) that some data is added. For much simpler , situation like here on stackoverflow, when some quesiton is added and it is become written that `N question with new activity`. I think that this issue have some contact with MySql triggers , but I don't know how to connect trigger to php. With any helpful advice will be very contented , thanks beforehand

Comment: This has nothing to do with triggers. You want web sockets, comet, long-polling, etc...

Comment: @MarcB can you show me some tutorial , or how to search it, what I have to learn ?

Comment: Do you mean you want a web page to know whether there is new content to be shown, without any user action (like a refresh)? If so, you could use something like a ‟heartbeat”, which is basically a `XMLHttpRequest` that triggers at a set interval. This is how Facebook and Twitter et al. automatically update pages with new content.

Comment: @ACJ yes, I want to know that. Are you sure that Facebook is updating content with time intervals ?

Comment: @ACJ In this way , server will not become slow ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure Facebook uses timed requests for some of the updating processes (it appears they also use persisting requests that await a server push), and yes, this can slow a server down. You have to figure out the optimal interval to set the ‟heartbeat” to, and you have to figure out what processes absolutely need to be called with the `XMLHttpRequest` and obviously drop the rest. jQuery and History.js are probably a good starting point.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the ugly answer I gave about the undefined there. didn't understand it at first. let me try and make it up to you with a descent answer here.

Comment: @guymograbi nothing to worry, happening , thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only layer that talks to Mysql is PHP.

PHP is rendered in server side. So once in client side, only HTML and JavaScript. This means that if you will use Mysql triggers, it will only be half way through.

The client/server side is more interesting. As answered in comments above, COMET is the umbrella name for the technologies used to achieve "live updates". [Stackoverflow uses web-sockets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox).

see their last line saying

```
Now for the gotchas - in order to use this feature you must have a browser that supports web sockets.
```

For the server side, there's no need to use Mysql triggers. A solution which is not DB implementation dependent would be much better. A simple subscribe/publish design patter would be good.